# Conditional compilation in flex

Tags: apache-flex, conditional-compilation

Is it possible to give conditional compilation as follows in flex?

```
applicationType::desktop || applicationType::web
{
   // common code for desktop & web
}

applicationType::desktop || applicationType::mobile
{
  //common code for desktop and mobile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes.

It depends on your usecase.

You can read more about conditional compiling in the [Flex Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7abd.html)